# Auto (drag)incrementing only one cell value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

For example, I have one table with values:

```
14.10%    
1.60%   
2.80%
```

and I have a cell with value I want to multiply each table row by, eg  `L15=300`

I want to multiply every value by 300, so I put

```
=A1*L15
=A2*L15
```

and then drag it down but unfortunately the `L15` is incrementing as well:

```
=A3*L17
=A4*L18 
etc.
```

Is there any way in excel to auto increment only first part of the equation (all A cells?)

Thank you

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much guys! This was bugging me a long time

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
=A1*$L$15
```

The dollar sign specifies an absolute (fixed) reference. Without the dollar sign, you'll get a relative reference by default, which is what you're seeing when you autofill.

More info [here](http://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2013/15.2).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use [absolute references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-538396b3-990e-4b44-9d9c-28b4151d7d21)

`$L$15`